# How to push html element

Tags: angularjs

first, iam using `AngularJS v1.3.14`
i try to `push` : `label` ,`input` ,`button` html element

here my html code:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ctrl" >
<div class="form-inline" ng-repeat="c in controls">
    <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control">
    <button class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add();">+</button>
```

and script code:

```
 angular.module("app", [])
        .controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.controls=[];
            $scope.add = function () {
                $scope.controls.push({
                 ...
                })
            };
        });
```

and my question is: how can i `push` `div` with `controls` id.

Comment: Have you considered using ng-repeat?

Comment: `ng-repeat`? but  how? i havnt any array!

Comment: Maybe that's the problem :)

Comment: for using `ng-repeat` u must have array of object agree?

Comment: Agreed. Perhaps I don't get what you're trying to do. But with AngularJS you're not supposed to work directly on the DOM. You reflect DOM with variables

Comment: Ok iam update my code but not working.

Comment: the controls you are pushing in the `$scope.controls.push(controls)` is undefined, thus not working. Try `$scope.controls.push({})` instead

Comment: See my working code man ! thanks

Comment: @Sphaso i updated code in `plnkr` but i have a question?how to remove `[object Object]` from `input` or `object` from array?see `console.log` please

Comment: @stackoverflowusername I've updated my answer. Ignore the PLNKR since it's outdated at this point.

Answer (score 0):

try this, you need to dynamically add the html controls in a array then re-rendering the array abject values by using `ng-repeat`

### Html code

```
  <div class="form-inline" ng-repeat="c in controls">

                        <div ng-bind-html="c.htmlValue | to_trusted"></div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add();">+</button>
```

### Js Code

```
    angular.module("app", [])
            .controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
                $scope.controls=[];
                $scope.add = function () {
        var stringValue="<label class=\'control-label\'>Name:</label><input class=\'form-control\'><button class=\'btn btn-danger\'>X</button>"
        $scope.controls.push({ "htmlValue": stringValue })
    };
            }).filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

See this working code in

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bm2boj6c8z1qtKagV4P5?p=preview)

### Demo Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The button was not inside the scope of the controller. At the bottom you can find a link with the PLNKR demonstratic a basic use.

```
angular.module("app", [])
        .controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.controls=[];
            $scope.add = function () {
                $scope.controls.push('')
            };
        });
```

HTML:

```
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl" >
    <div class="container" >
<div class="form-inline" ng-repeat="c in controls">
    <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="c">
    <button class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add();">+</button>
</div>
  </body>
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/d7wUyzjbY2dU0hcdGuel?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the solution:
html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="form-inline" ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $index">
    <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="todos[$index]">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove($index);">X</button>
</div>
<div class="form-inline">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add();">+</button>
</div>
```

scripts:

```
        angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.todos = [''];
            $scope.add = function () {
                $scope.todos.push({});
                console.log($scope.todos);
            };
            $scope.remove = function (index) {
                $scope.todos.splice(index, 1);
            };
        });
```

hope this help.